# Why and how should I write and read from binary files?

Tags: c++, binary, binaryfiles

I'm coding a game project as a hobby and I'm currently in the part where I need to store some resource data (.BMPs for example) into a file format of my own so my game can parse all of it and load into the screen.

For reading BMPs, I read the header, and then the RGB data for each pixel, and I have a array[width][height] that stores these values.

I was told I should save these type of data in binary, but not the reason. I've read about binary and what it is (the 0-1 representation of data), but why should I use it to save a .BMP data for example?
If I'm going to read it later in the game, doesn't it just adds more complexness and maybe even slow down the loading process?

And lastly, if it is better to save in binary (I'm guessing it is, seeing as how everyone seems to do so from what I researched in other game resource files) how do I read and write binary in C++?
I've seen lots of questions but with many different ways for many different types of variables, so I'm asking which is the best/more C++ish way of doing it?

Comment: bmp is a format with a specification available to others, if you want to use it, you need to write in that format so other programs that normally can open bmp files will be able to read them too. If only you want to be able to read those files, save it in whatever format you want, but dont name the files in a way people could mistake them for other formats.

Comment: Here binary most likely means not as text.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have it all backwards.  A computer processor operates with data at the binary level.  Everything in a computer is binary.  To deal with data in human-readable form, we write functions that jump through hoops to make that binary data look like something that humans understand.  So if you store your .BMP data in a file as text, you're actually making the computer do a whole lot more work to convert the .BMP data from its natural binary form into text, and then from its text form back into binary in order to display it.

The truth of the matter is that the more you can handle data in its raw binary form, the faster your code will be able to run.  Less conversions means faster code.  But there's obviously a tradeoff:  If you need to be able to look at data and understand it without pulling out a magic decoder ring, then you might want to store it in a file as text.  But in doing so, we have to understand that there is conversion processing that must be done to make that human-readable text meaningful to the processor, which as I said, operates on nothing but pure binary data.

---

And, just in case you already knew that or sort-of-knew-it, and your question was "why should I open my .bmp file in binary mode and not in text mode", then the reason for that is that opening a file in text mode asks the platform to perform CRLF-to-LF conversions ("\r\n"-to-"\n" conversions), as necessary based on the platform, so that at the internal string-processing level, all you're dealing with is '\n' characters.  If your file consists of binary data, you don't want that conversion going on, or else it will corrupt the data from the file as you read it.  In this state, most of the data will be fine, and things may work fine most of the time, but occasionally you'll run across a pair of bytes of the hexadecimal form 0x0d,0x0a (decimal 13,10) that will get converted to just 0x0a (10), and you'll be missing a byte in the data you read.  Therefore be sure to open binary files in binary mode!

---

OK, based on your most recent comment (below), here's this:

As you (now?) understand, data in a computer is stored in binary format.  Yes, that means it's in 0's and 1's.  However, when programming, you don't actually have to fiddle with the 0's and 1's yourself, unless you're doing bitwise logical operations for some reason.  A variable of type, let's say `int` for example, is a collection of individual bits, each of which can be either 0 or 1.  It's also a collection of bytes, and assuming that there are 8 bits in a byte, then there are generally 2, 4, or 8 bytes in an `int`, depending on your platform and compiler options.  But you work with that `int` as an `int`, not as individual 0's and 1's.  If you write that `int` out to a file in its purest form, the bytes (and thus the bits) get written out in an unconverted raw form.  But you could also convert them to ASCII text and write them out that way.  If you're displaying an `int` on the screen, you don't want to see the individual 0's and 1's of course, so you print it in its ASCII form, generally decoded as a decimal number.  You could just as easily print that same `int` in its hexadecimal form, and the result would look different even though it's the same number.  For example, in decimal, you might have the decimal value 65.  That same value in hexadecimal is 0x41 (or, just 41 if we understand that it's in base 16).  That same value is the letter 'A' if we display it in ASCII form (and consider only the low byte of the 2,- 4,- or 8-byte `int`, i.e. treat it as a `char`).

For the rest of this discussion, forget that we were talking about an `int` and now consider that we're discussing a `char`, or 1 byte (8 bits).  Let's say we still have that same value, 65, or 0x41, or 'A', however you want to look at it.  If you want to send that value to a file, you can send it in its raw form, or you can convert it to text form.  If you send it in its raw form, it will occupy 8 bits (one byte) in the file.  But if you want to write it to the file in text form, you'd convert it to ASCII, which depending on the format you want to write it an the actual value (65 in this case), it will occupy either 1, 2, or 3 bytes.  Say you want to write it in decimal ASCII with no padding characters.  The value 65 will then take 2 bytes: one for the '6' and one for the '5'.  If you want to print it in hexadecimal form, it will still take 2 bytes: one for the '4' and one for the '1', unless you prepend it with "0x", in which case it will take 4 bytes, one for '0', one for 'x', one for '4', and another for '1'.  Or suppose your `char` is the value 255 (the maximum value of a `char`): If we write it to the file in decimal ASCII form, it will take 3 bytes.  But if we write that same value in hexadecimal ASCII form, it will still take 2 bytes (or 4, if we're prepending "0x"), because the value 255 in hexadecimal is 0xFF.  Compare this to writing that 8-bit byte (`char`) in its raw binary form:  A `char` takes 1 byte (by definition), so it will consume only 1 byte of the file in binary form regardless of what its value is.

Comment: I see, thanks for the info. But if I'm going to fill my array[width][height] with the RGB info from a image, don't I need to convert it to a readable format so I can properly fill the array?
Or am I supposed to work with 0-1s for these operations? I'm guessing I'd need to convert binary to char (0-255 range) for the values.

Comment: Yes, I understand the benefit of writing in binary files, thank you very much! Most places I've searched gave me this same definition, but I couldn't grasp the benefit of saving space from it.

Comment: @Danicco - It's not so much a "saving space" issue, though that does have merit, as it is a "don't have to perform any conversion" issue.  Also, if you're storing bitmaps in files by themselves, you might want to make your program write & read bitmaps in true .bmp format, so you can easily swap out images, etc.  If you're dumping a bunch of miscellaneous stuff in a single file, though, obviously that doesn't matter.

Comment: @Danicco - Actually, I take that back.  It's not so much a "saving space" issue as it is a "less file I/O" issue.  The less I/O involved with reading & writing a file, the faster it will go.  Yes, not having to convert the ASCII into raw data helps, but I think the bigger issue is the file I/O burden of having to read & write extra bytes.